# Magento - sales email addresses that are not common

Tags: sql, magento

Magento won't let me save email address of the form 'contact@mysite.camera', saying:

```
Invalid email address "contact@mysite.camera"
```

But this address is indeed valid. How can I set it to my real email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution (worked for me) is to change the database manually. You have to be very careful when doing this. In any case, the entries appear in the table core_config_data:

```
mysql> select * from core_config_data where path like 'trans_email%';
+-----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                            | value                 |
+-----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
|       760 | default |        0 | trans_email/ident_general/name  | Owner                 |
|       761 | default |        0 | trans_email/ident_general/email | contact@mysite.camera |
|       762 | default |        0 | trans_email/ident_sales/name    | Sales                 |
|       763 | default |        0 | trans_email/ident_sales/email   | contact@mysite.camera |
|       764 | default |        0 | trans_email/ident_support/name  | CustomerSupport       |
|       765 | default |        0 | trans_email/ident_support/email | contact@mysite.camera |
|       766 | default |        0 | trans_email/ident_custom1/name  | Custom 1              |
|       767 | default |        0 | trans_email/ident_custom1/email | contact@mysite.camera |
|       768 | default |        0 | trans_email/ident_custom2/name  | Custom 2              |
|       769 | default |        0 | trans_email/ident_custom2/email | contact@mysite.camera |
+-----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------+----------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The problem is that if this is a fresh installation of magento and you haven't saved any email addresses yet, these values will not appear in the table, and magento uses that default. To overcome that, you need to first save valid email addresses (just set it to any valid email address, say sales@me.com), and then you will see the entries in your DB.